# How to prevent re-render of parent route using React-Router and Framer Motion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, framer-motion

I'm using Framer Motion with React Router to create animations between different routes.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJt-FtzJ5fo

I'll try to summarize the problem in the following points:

I'm using React Router v6 for routing, I have multiple nested routes and parallel switches for different components on my app, which is a simple catalog.

I've added transitions to each page's {content} component and leaving the {footer} and {header} components on different switches to prevent them from animating.

I've also added location={location} key={location.pathname} to the switch component and exitBeforeEnter to the AnimatePresence wrapper.

The issue becomes apparent when accesing one of the catalog's items, whose route is "es/:catalogid/:id", which is dynamic and shown as an overlay over the previous page. Accesing these routes affects the previous route, located at "/es/", and triggering the animation.

How would one go about preventing this issue?

[Framer Motion and React router 5: How do I prevent re-render of parent components with nested routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729412/framer-motion-and-react-router-5-how-do-i-prevent-re-render-of-parent-component) this is almost exactly the same issue, but the codesandboxes are not working and the solution isn't either.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I've posted the answer addressing a similar question to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67015564/3586616)

Answer (score 2):

Sharing your code might help to add some clarity on implementation.

My guess is that setting `key={location.pathname}` on your Switch component is causing a re-render of the whole page, which is then triggering the animation.

React Router's [location.pathname](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) is tied to the current url. As an example if you go from the route `es/myItems` to `es/myItems/myFirstItemDetail`, that will be reflected in `location.pathname`

It doesn't matter if the catalog's route is nested, when a parent component's key changes, React will re-render that parent and all child elements.

From ["4 methods to force a re-render in React"](https://linguinecode.com/post/4-methods-to-re-render-react-component):

```
By changing the value of the key prop, it will make React unmount the component and re-mount it again, and go through the render() lifecycle.
```

I also found this explainer helpful: [Understanding React's Key Prop](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop)

Try using a different value for that Switch's key that's not dependent on stuff happening with its children.

Comment: the question is prevent re-render, not force re-render.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of goodmorningasif is correct. I had this very same problem because I was using `key={location.key}`. The key of a route changes every time anything on the route changes, and that includes route params and route args.

Since you are already using `location.pathname` my suggestion is that, instead of using route params you use just search strings. This will not change the route pathname and you will be able to read it from inside the component to determine what to read. You can even use the `Route` component to just render the inner component when the search string matches:

```js
<Link to={{search: 'itemId=itemA'}} >Item A</Link>
<Route path={{ search: "itemId" }}>
// if itemId == itemA...
</Route>
```

It is not clear in the docs, but you can use a [location object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object) almost everywhere you can use location as string. Using the object allows you to provide just the search string, which will not change the current path.